# TCPDF Blank Page when saving the pdf in Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, tcpdf

I'm getting a blank page when saving the PDF in Chrome, but it works perfectly during the preview. PDF also works perfectly when saving and previewing in Firefox.
How would I solve this issue? 
I've been researching this one, I saw that it's because of GZIP compression, but i'm not sure how to turn that off. Can someone guide me how to combat this battle!

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39356741/5249203

Answer (score 2):

`$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D');`

Fixed the problem for me, THANKS a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same irritating problem.  A work around is to output the pdf directly to a file using

```
$pdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'D');
```

You won't get the preview in the browser, but the saved file will have all the data.

The problem is that when the PDF is saved from the browser preview, the POST data is not sent again.